# I got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on subdomain

Tags: apache

I have script to deploy auto my wordpress on apache2 automatically whenever developer commit code to any branch with subdomain is branchname but I’m receiving ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. My site is https://feature_fabfitfuntheme.shop.fffdev.com/ The strange thing is that when I go to a sub-page such as https://feature_fabfitfuntheme.shop.fffdev.com/welcome/ it works perfectly fine. This is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This would seem to be something in the WordPress config, rather than `.htaccess` (which is just the default and doesn't do anything particular when subdomains are accessed).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error. The problem is I’ve used a mix of upper and lower case characters in my WordPress General setting URLs. To fix this condition, I must use lowercase URLs in my WordPress General setting URLs.
[image]